# What are the cases that a BindableProperty's propertyChanged is called multiple times?

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a custom control that has an `ItemsSource`  property, that I set in XAML like so:

```xml
<Controls:RadioButtonsGroup Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding lstGender}" Orientation="Horizontal" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGender}" HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
```

backing property:

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemsSource), typeof(IEnumerable<object>), typeof(RadioButtonsGroup), propertyChanged: OnItemsSourceChanged);
```

the problem is that the `OnItemsSourceChanged`method is called multiple times  when I go back from the page and enter it again.

Comment: Find out what code is making any changes (assigning, Add(), Clear(), etc.) on your `lstGender` property.

Comment: I guess that to set the property, to add, change or remove itens will raise this event.

Comment: but I only bind it in XAML